# Display output of a Bash command and keeping the output in a variable

Tags: bash, stdout, backticks

I'm not sure if it is possible but what I want to do is to run a bash command and storing the output in a variable AND display it as if I launched the command normally. Here is my code:

```
VAR=`svn checkout $URL`
```

So I want to store the output in VAR and still see the result (and because svn checkout takes a long time, I can't do echo $VAR just after..)

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If the command is run from a terminal, you can do:

```
VAR=$(svn checkout $URL | tee /dev/tty)
```

Comment: Gah, beat me to it by seconds!

Comment: Maybe because I tested the above with `v=$(for i in $(seq 20); do echo $i; sleep 0.2; done | tee /dev/tty)`, and you used `sleep 1`? :-)

Comment: Note that this does not work when executed by Github Actions due to the lack of a tty (see https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/241 )

Comment: thanks @AshutoshJindal, saved me some trouble

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to call the external `tee`:

```
VAR=$(svn checkout $URL) && echo $VAR
```

or even:

```
VAR=$(svn checkout $URL); echo $VAR
```

Comment: I think the idea was that `svn` takes a long time, and the OP wanted to see the output of the `svn` command in realtime, instead of after it ended.  He even says so in the question :-)

Comment: I think I need to get some help on literacyoverflow!